# Java: Using same instance of a class in various other classes

Tags: java, oop, architecture, static, constructor

it might be stupid question, but I dont know the answer to it and I dont know where to search the answer, so it would be nice if someone could help me.

I've a class (lets name it A) with different members and methods. I use the methods of this class in another class (lets name it B).

For every B-Object created I want to use the SAME instance of A. Is that possible?
Actually I have a constructor in B where I call A a = new A(); Of course I always get different instances of this class.

How can I now change this? I know it could be possible to solve it with spring framework (inject always the same object into the instances of B), but I cant use it. How else could this problem be solved?

Thank you very much for your help! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers! :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes its possible.  You need to define a singleton instance of classA that is static, and use it wherever you want.

So there are multiple ways of doing this:

```
public class ClassA {
   public static ClassA classAInstance = new ClassA();  

}
```

then anywhere you can do

```
ClassA.classAInstance.whatever();
```

This is simple, but it might be enough for you.

If you really want to use the singleton pattern, look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for a Java example.  The advantage of this approach is that it makes sure that you only have 1 classA instance.

Answer (score 7):

To elaborate on other answers:

```
public class A
{
private static A instance;
private A()
{
    ...
}

public static A getInstance()
{
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new A();

    return instance;
}
...
public void doSomething()
{
    ... 
}
}
```

And then call in B like this:

```
A.getInstance().doSomething();
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may want A to be a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern used to implement the mathematical concept of a singleton, by restricting the instantiation of a class to one object.

This means your existing code will have to modified to use some kind of `getInstance()` method, but once that change has been made all instances of class B will use a single instance of class A.

Here is a direct link to the: [simplest example from the above site.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Traditional_simple_way)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a static class and make sure it's public.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can use singleton design pattern to share the same instance every-time but if you want to use a same instance with parameters(overloaded constructor)..you cannot use SINGLETON